# How do I prove e^w=z? (I wrote the proof process instead of photo)

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Our motivation for the definition of the logarithmic function is based on solving the equation $$(1) e^w=z$$ for w, where z is any nonzero complex number. To do this, we note that when z and w are written $$z=re^i\theta (-\pi<\theta<=\pi)$$ and $$w=u+iv$$, equation (1) becomes $$e^u*e^ie^v=re^i\theta$$ This tells us that $$e^u=r$$ and $$v=a\theta+2n\pi$$ where n is any integer. Since the equation
$$e^u=r$$ is the same as $$u=lnr$$, it follows that equation (1) is satisfied if and only if w has one of the values $$w=lnr+i(\theta+2n\pi) (n is integer)$$. Thus, we write ***$$(2) logz=lnr+i(\theta+2n\pi) (n is integer)$$***, equation (1) tells us that (3)e^(logz)=z (z=/0)

This is from "complex variables and applications, 9th edition, Brown). I cannot understand (2) equation. Why is it logz, not lnz?

Comment: This is difficult to read. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is hard to read. But if I had to guess... $\ln(r)$ refers to a singleton and $\log(z)$ refers to a set.

Comment: I would not put too much thought into “$\log$ vs $\ln$.” Different people use different conventions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove e^w=z?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286656/how-do-i-prove-ew-z)